# pip upgrade not working

Tags: upgrade, python, pip

I am trying to upgrade pip from version 7.1.2 to 8.0.2
But I am not able to upgrade it due to some errors. I ran the following command.

```
user@ubuntu:~/devstack$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

I am getting following Traceback errors:

[image: Screenshot of output]
[image: Screenshot of output continue]

Please let me know how can I make it work.

Comment: I posted a posible solution in the next link:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/57416371/7391092](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57416371/7391092)

Answer (score 7):

You can either upgrade `pip` globally using `sudo`:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo pip2 install --upgrade pip
```

Or you can upgrade it for your user only using the `--user` option:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --user pip
pip2 install --upgrade --user pip
```

Note that I upgrade both `pip`s for Python 2 and Python 3. It's important to upgrade the version for Python 3 first, because the one you upgrade last will later be accessible through `pip`, which must be `pip2` by default.

---

**Important update:**

As of `pip` version 10 (I think), the `pip`/`pip3` command is broken, due to a change in the package structure which is not compatible with the launch scripts provided from the `python-pip`/`python3-pip` packages from `apt`. See [Error after upgrading pip: cannot import name 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49836676/4464570) on Stack Overflow for details.

Quick fix: Don't run `pip`/`pip3` any more, but instead always use `python -m pip`/`python3 -m pip`, which will not use the now incompatible executable scripts provided from your system's package manager, or don't upgrade your `pip`/`pip3` version to 10 or higher.

Comment: Note that if you choose to use `sudo`, you will overwrite the system Pip, which is likely to be owned by the package manager – this can lead to problems in the future, if the package manager notices your changes.

Comment: @Josh I don't think so. A `sudo pip` install/upgrade would end up in `/usr/local/bin`, the package manager's `python-pip` is placed in `/usr/bin`. They can peacefully coexist, just the one in local will take precedence due to the PATH order.

Comment: Oh, cool – last time I tried `sudo pip` it borked my install, but if it works now, then that's awesome.

Comment: I upgraded pip3 from 9.0.1 to 18.0 using `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`.  As @ByteCommander says, pip3 works due to the PATH order, but ...  If I try `/usr/bin/pip3 --version` in Ubuntu 16.04, I get the response, "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main"  The, I get a crash window popping up.

Comment: @Diagon There is some incompatibility between the scripts used to launch pip from the command line and the updated internal pip python packages starting with version 10. See my edited answer.

Comment: @ByteCommander - do you know how to uininstall pip & pip3 from /usr/local/bin?  Then I'd apt-get install --reinstall pip3 to get back to version 8.

Comment: @Diagon The Stack Overflow post I linked covers that in detail.

Comment: in the latest version `pip3` , the `main()` is moved to `pip._internal`. The import statement should be changed to `from pip._internal import main`

Answer (score 0):

I also run into this problem when I wanted to upgrade system `pip` `pip3` from 9.0.1 to 19.2.3.

After running `pip3 install --upgrade pip`, `pip` version becomes 19.2.3. But `main()` has been moved in `pip._internal` in the latest version, which leaves `pip3` broken.

So in file `/usr/bin/pip3`, replace `line 9`: `from pip import main` with `from pip._internal import main`. The issue will be fixed, works the same for `python2-pip`. (Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 distribution)