# After running "pip install --upgrade pip" pip tells me the same thing

Tags: 16.04, python, pip

While install a package:

```
....................
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Ok:

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 961kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: Probably because you *use* the system-wide `pip`, which is still 8.1.1, whereas you *updated* a local (user-only) `pip`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/726850/pip-upgrade-not-working

Comment: Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases. To fix this problem, I'm trying to install it using this command: python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools virtualenv

Comment: So did your solution work??

Answer (score 5):

To upgrade `pip` using `pip` is a bit different than regular command. Use

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Here `python -m` will read the `pip` library file as a script and you will be able to update.

Answer (score 4):

If you were like me you had created a virtual environment in a project folder.
`python -m venv env`

So in order to make the pip upgrade work, go into the Scripts folder of the env folder.

Then run `.\python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Ditto with any pip installs. Same folder `.\pip install ....`

The `.\` pins it to the command in the current folder, be it `pip` or `python`.

(I was doing this on Windows. But `./` would be the equivalent for Unix variants)

PS: I also ran those commands as Administrator - so sudo the commands if things fails.

Answer (score 3):

Run the command to upgrade pip as root so pip can be upgraded if it is installed in the following location:

```
$ pip -V
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Command to upgrade pip:

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Command to upgrade pip3 (for Python 3.x):

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Explanation of the `--upgrade` option of `pip install`:

```
-U, --upgrade
             Upgrade all packages to the newest available version. This
             process is recursive regardless of whether a dependency is
             already satisfied.
```

Comment: My first foray into Python tonight and it said: *"You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 18.1 is available."*. Running `pip --version` returns: `pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`. My plan is to do nothing unless a problem occurs then I'll look at upgrading. Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, Kernel 4.14.78.

Comment: The results of `pip -V` after updating pip today are `pip 18.1` - the same version as the latest pip version that is currently available - so the upgrade to pip 18.1 works, but as you wrote there's no reason to upgrade pip unless a problem occurs.

Comment: Did nothing for me. I still get the same result for `pip -V`.

Comment: You may have an issue with the path to the pip3 executable file that is preventing your system from using the pip3 that is installed by `sudo apt install python3-pip`. This can be caused by installing another version of Python 3.x or by Anaconda (if you are using Anaconda)

Comment: This is a violation of [DontBreakDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#A.27make_install.27_can_conflict_with_packages)--and will cause you nothing but headaches down the road! It's ok to install whatever you want locally, but installing things globally like this without an apt package will complicate updates.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how it is done for pip-8 on Ubuntu-16, but I guess you could do it the same way I updated my pip-9 on Ubuntu-18 to current pip-20:

On Linux or macOS:

```
pip install -U pip
```

globally or for specific versions/installations:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
python3 -m pip install -U pip
python3.8 -m pip install -U pip
etc.
```

On Windows:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

[Source](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip)

Cause line "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" from [Installing packages using pip and virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

`__main__.py` was moved to `_internal` in the later versions of python. This file should not exist in `dist-packages` or `.local`.

Try one of these based on what python version you are using. Then try `pip2 -V`. Worst case, you can put them back.

```
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages __main__.py /tmp
pip3 -V
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages __main__.py /tmp
pip2 -V
sudo mv ~.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages __main__.py /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about it unless you have a problem. I was following the [Google quick start to using Python to manipulate gmail.com](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) tonight. I did the following:

```
$ pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client oauth2client
Collecting google-api-python-client
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/92/e4746e646585c8c359781c19984fe8b6b8794a6cfe382cd481329d5252ac/google-api-python-client-1.7.4.tar.gz (141kB)
    (... SNIP ...)
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So as you can see Ubuntu is still distributing `8.1.1` but now version `18.1` is available whereas a four months ago `10.0.1` was available.

I've read many times how people upgrading `pip` and `python` got burned so my advise would be to do nothing unless you run into problems and feel a forced upgrade is necessary to correct them.

I've learned the hard way *"If it's not broken don't fix it"*.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, try to modify the installation command:

```
pip3.5 install absl-py
```

with

`pip3.5 install --user absl-py`