# `pip3 search <pkg_name>` shows version that it refuses to install

Tags: python3, pip

`pip3 search aiohttp` produces (among other things):

```
aiohttp (3.3.2)  - Async http client/server framework (asyncio)
  INSTALLED: 2.3.10
  LATEST:    3.3.2
```

Nevertheless, `pip3 install --upgrade --user aiohttp` responds that it's already up to date, and `pip3 install --user aiohttp==3.3.2` returns:

```
[...] Could not find a version that satisfies
the requirement aiohttp==3.3.2 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 
[... snip ...], 2.3.10, 3.0.0b0) No matching distribution found for
aiohttp==3.3.2
```

Python3 is v.3.5.2, and pip3 is v.18.0, which is an upgrade to the system's python3-pip v.8.1.1.  Pip3 was upgraded locally using `pip3 upgrade --user`.  See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1068719/242522) for links and discussion.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82337/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-diagon). (all comments have been moved as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue, which we debugged via chat, is that you upgraded `pip`.  This causes some... incompatibilities (and there's terminal dumps in the chat room from a 16.04 container to support this).

**Step 1: Remove the upgraded `pip` versions**

This one's easy, since you installed it in your local data - `pip3 uninstall pip`

This will remove the version of it in your local userspace.

**Step 2: Close your terminal or SSH session, then reestablish it**.

This is so the session forgets about the local userspace `pip3` binary.

**Step 3: Run the installation steps again for the PyPI packages you're after** - `pip3 install --upgrade --user aiohttp stig` (this also installs `stig`, too, which you mentioned in chat was your goal)

This should install `aiohttp` version `3.4.0` (latest in PyPI as of this post) and `stig`.

---

We did all this in chat, and it installed `aiohttp` without issues.  The problem with upgrading `pip` versions is **it will increase the chances that `pip` will not work** since newer `pip` versions rely heavily on also having an updated Python version.  And unless you are using `virtualenv`s for your Python environments, you're stuck on the system's Python 3.5.2, of which the newer `pip` does not behave with.  (Note that this was also recognized during our tests).

Also note that `aiohttp` has a requirement listed on PyPI of Python 3.5.3 or higher.  This is not going to be resolved within a 16.04 environment, so you may need to resort to Python virtual environments with more updated Python, or VMs running Ubuntu 18.04, or containers (such as [LXD based containers](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/)) with 18.04.  This gives you a more updated Python version.